# Certificate - Subject Alternative Name missing - Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, reverse-proxy

I deployed Apache Reverse Proxy so that our Cyber team can access the SolarWinds. Cyber team will access the reverse Proxy server and Backend Server will be SolarWinds, I can login and see the SolarWinds Main Page but there are few features which are not showing.

On reverse proxy i generated SSL using openssl

```
/usr/bin/openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key -nodes -x509 -days 365 -out /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt
```

and Solarwinds came with its own SSL.

When i run the developer tools there it is showing errors like

```
apolloisolate?44308.49.L:17 POST https://sworion-01.domain_name/api2/swis/query?lang=en-us&swAlertOnError=false&swLogOutOnAuthError=true&viewId=1 net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

I tried to match the certificates of solarwinds and ReverseProxy and in reverse proxy it is saying that " Certificate - Subject Alternative Name missing "

Could this be the reason ? If yes is there a way to oversome/bypass it

Comment: `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` - have you added the certificate to the trust-anchor store which the developer tools use?  If not, it won't trust the proxy's certificate.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: A certificate  isn't trusted simply because it's a certificate.  You need to tell your client application to trust it.  This is done by adding it to the trust-anchor store of your client.  If your proxy certificate was issued by a commercial CA then there's a good chance that it's already trusted by virtue of the CA which signed it (or more likely, the CA which signed the CA which signed your certificate) already being in your trust-anchor store (added by the OS).  For locally generated certificates you need to manually add it.  How depends on the application.

Comment: Yes, This is locally generated SSL , i import it in browser, but still facing same issue